# Eclipse - same package-name different projects. Which one will be activated by Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, project, visibility, package

I have two different Eclipse IDE Projects, which contain a equally named packages with.

**Project one:**

```
 com.example.test
 |_ lib.java
```

**Project two:**

```
 com.example.test
 |_ lib.java
```

Now, when I do import the lib.java inside of the Package one -
the lib.java inside of the pakcage two is used.

**Questions:**

Shouldn't the Files in different Projects be independant from each other? 
How is that possible, that I can enter a file from another Eclipse project?

Comment: _Why_ do you have it set up like this?

Comment: It was a temporary set-up, because I have some code, which I wrote in a separate Project, in order to integrate it into another one. During the integration I mentioned the issue, described above.

Comment: do the projects mention each other at all in either the .project or .classpath file?

Comment: no, they don't mention each other

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eclipse adds packages from ALL Projects, which are open in workspace.
It is not defined, which package will be used, when 2 Projects with same package names exist.

Answer (score 1):

This is a build path issue. You either have #2 as a required project on #1's build path, or you have #2 as a jar on #1's build path.

The best solution would be to not use the same package across two projects. Choose a package name that differentiates the two projects.

Comment: No, there is no visible connection between those two Projects. Nor as an imported jar, neither as a dependant Project. When I closed Project two - the code in Project one was used, as intended.

Answer (score 0):

You should not use classes from other projects that don't have dependencies to your project. This is not portable, since other users who try to use your project will not where to find the missing classes.

You should explicitly add the required projects as dependencies in the builld path. Otherwise, Eclipse will try to guess where he can find your classes.

Comment: i was surprised about the possibility to use classes from other projects, without explicitely defining a dependency to them. My question was: is it intended to have the possibility of using code from another projects, without an explicit dependency, or is it an Eclipse Bug? Where can I find some documentation about the inter/intraproject visibility?

Comment: Well, `Eclipse` wants to make development as easy as possible and this comes at a price.
My experience tells me that you should always test your application outside `Eclipse` before you use it in production environment.

Comment: You are missing the point. The question is: is it an intended behaviour, to load code from other projects?

Comment: That is what I mean: I think it is intended in order to simplify development, but I have no documentation source for this claim.